# Is creating a user in my database from gapi.client.oauth2.userinfo secure?

Tags: security, oauth-2.0, google-api, google-plus, google-authentication

I am registering a button with `gapi.signin.render`

I then use  `gapi.client.load('oauth2', 'v2');`
and `gapi.client.oauth2.userinfo.get().execute();`

I send the user email and name to my server to create an account for the user.
My concern is, anyone could POST that info to my server, I'm not verifying anything.

Is there a GET url that Google provides that I send the Access token to and receive the email back to ensure that the user has authorised? Figure I must be missing something :-/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not safe to just send the profile details via ajax. You should send the access_token to the server and have the server perform an authenticated [people.get](https://developers.google.com/+/api/latest/people/get) API request to get the details.

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/me?access_token=xyz123
```

Comment: Thanks that's what I figured, was just wondering if there was some other way around having to do that!